# Application.handle from DLL

Tags: delphi

Delphi.
How from DLL to learn Handle the appendix which has caused this DLL?

That is necessary: Knowing Handle appendices, I wish in Dll to use this Handle at creation of dialogues, because dialogue created as TOpendialog.Create(nil) sometimes it appears under the main window of the basic form. And so, in DLL I would make:

```
application.handle:=GetExeHandle; // GetExeHandle - How to learn?
Opendialog1:=TOpendialog.Create(application);
...
```

So it is correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only time your DLL shows a dialog box is when the host application calls a function from your DLL. Include the parent window handle as one of the function's input parameters so that the EXE can tell you which handle to use. Do not attempt to discover the handle yourself. As a library developer, you cannot guess what the host application is doing.

If you don't want to include the handle on every function call, then add an initialization function that users of the DLL need to call before any other functions. Pass the handle in the initialization and then store it in a variable in your DLL so that other functions can use the value when they need it.

Comment: I.e. from dll to learn handle it is absolutely impossible? :(

Comment: Gu, the host application may have any number of windows, including *zero*. Can you think of a way to know which of those windows is the "main" window, if you don't know anything else about the nature of the host application? And what if the "main" window doesn't belong to the thread that's calling your DLL function? Do what *all other* DLLs do and shift the burden to the host: Require the host to *tell you* which handle to use for dialog parents.

Comment: @Gu passing the parent handle into a DLL is standard practice in the Windows API (often within a record [struct] type, e.g  TASKDIALOGCONFIG http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, has made procedure of initialization InitDll (h:thandle); {begin application.handle: = h; end;}, after loading dll I cause InitDll (application.handle), a question: in dll it is enough to make application.handle: = h; or it is necessary still application before it to create?

Comment: it's HWND rather than THandle

Comment: Application.Handle := h is correct coding in a DLL. Application object is automatically created for you.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you use runtime packages (and you don't, or not the right ones), you are in for a world of pain.

Your library will have its' own copy not only of `(T)Application` but also of thread sycnhronization queue and event (and everything else).

What you are trying to do can seem to work, but it may (and it will) break anytime cause any complex dialog, regardless if VCL or WinAPI, does its' own message pumping, which will bypass the applications' idle and synchronization handling, resulting in reentrancy issues and random stalls or deadlocks.

You *may* try to handle a lot of the cases by copying the applications' handles, events etc. to the DLL's globals upon its' initialization (is I tried to do), but (not only) if you use anything like `TApplication` or `TThread` in the DLL, it *will* break sometimes.

You can avoid these problems if you use the right BPL runtime packages in your app and the library, as they will share the same namespace and globals as the application using them.

Comment: You can only use packages if your host app is a Delphi app built with the same version of the compiler as the DLL. Sometimes you do need to show dialogs from a DLL. For example, it is essential if you show UI from a COM Office add-in.

Comment: Ah, of course, my answer applies to Delphi applications. If your host app isn't built in Delphi, there is a chance it will not suffer from these issues.

Comment: Well, you still have to deal with the issues, but it's really not that hard.